# C++ Segfault No compile errors can't find cause

Tags: c++

Hoping someone can help. I'm able to compile with no error, I'm not finding any syntax errors but when I run this, it crashes. Debug segfaults on launch. Full disclosure, this is homework. I'm not asking for someone to code this, just look at my problem and my existing code and maybe point me toward what I did that broke this so badly?

Question: You found an exciting summer job for five weeks. It pays, say, $15.50 per hour. Suppose that the total tax you pay on your summer job income is 14%. After paying the taxes you spend 10 % of your net income to buy new clothes and other accessories for the next school year and 1% to buy school supplies. After buying clothes and school supplies, you use 25% of the remaining money to buy savings bonds. For each dollar you spend to buy savings bonds, your parents spend $0.50 to buy additional savings bonds for you. Write a program that prompts the user to enter the pay rate for an hour and the number of hours you worked each week. The program then outputs the following:
 a. Your income before and after taxes from your summer job.
 b. The money you spend on clothes and other accessories.
 c. The money you spend on school supplies.
 d. The money you spend to buy savings bonds.
 e. The money your parents spend to buy additional savings bonds for you.

Code:

```
// Libraries defined 
#include <iomanip>  
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

//Main function 
int main () 

{ 

//Input variables 
    double hourlyrate; 
    double hweek1; 
    double hweek2; 
    double hweek3; 
    double hweek4; 
    double hweek5; 

//Output variables 
    double beforetax; 
    double netincome; 
    double clothmoney; 
    double suppliesmoney; 
    double moneyonbonds; 
    double additionalbonds; 
    double remain; 

//This statement takes care of the decimal places 
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);  

//Input from user 
    cout << "Enter your hourly rate: " << hourlyrate; 
    cin >> hourlyrate; 
    cout << "Week 1: " << hweek1; 
    cin >> hweek1; 
    cout << "Week 2: " << hweek2; 
    cin >> hweek2; 
    cout << "Week 3: " << hweek3; 
    cin >> hweek3; 
    cout << "Week 4: " << hweek4; 
    cin >> hweek4; 
    cout << "Week 5: " << hweek5; 
    cin >> hweek5; 

//Mathematics 
    beforetax = hourlyrate * (hweek1 + hweek2 + hweek3 + hweek4+ 
    hweek5) ; 
    netincome = beforetax - beforetax * 0.14; 
    clothmoney = netincome * 0.1; 
    suppliesmoney = netincome * 0.01; 
    remain = netincome - clothmoney - suppliesmoney; 
    moneyonbonds = remain * 0.25; 
    additionalbonds = static_cast<double>(moneyonbonds) * .50; 

//Output to user 
    cout << endl << "Income before tax = $" << beforetax << endl 
    << "Net income = $" << netincome << endl << "Money for clothes/accesories = $"
    << clothmoney << endl << "Money for supplies = $"<< suppliesmoney << endl 
    << "Money for saving bonds = $" << moneyonbonds << endl 
    << "Additional saving bonds money = $" << additionalbonds; 


return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: When it crashes, do you get a stack trace?

Comment: Why are you printing the hourly rates before you've initialized or entered the values?  It looks weird.  (Ditto with the hourly rate).  Don't forget to output a newline (or use `endl`) at the end.  And, given that `moneyonbonds` is defined as a `double`, what do you think `static_cast<double>(moneyonbonds)` is doing (other than cluttering up the program)?  Is it a relic from an experiment that didn't fix the problem?

Comment: I don't see any way this program can segfault.  Are you sure that's what's happening?

Comment: How do you compile and link your code?

Comment: This program should print lots of random numbers after each prompt for input, but it doesn't look like it should segfault.

Comment: no pointer, no reference, etc.  doesn't look like your program should seg fault.... ah, correction.  as it turns out, some compilers do put in a debug break when a variable is used before initialization.  that can show up as segmentation fault in certain environments if it is not trapped properly.

Comment: Doesn't segfault for me. and seems to work as desired, other than printing the uninitialized values in the wrong place.

Comment: Apart from the prompts all ending in '0.00', it seems to work fine when I compile and run it.

Comment: Well how can they be 0.00 since they are not initialized?  You guys are using a compiler that does that for you.  Not all do, this is UB.

Comment: @kfsone that was my point to those guys.  I'm saying that they can not count on it being 0.00 for everyone.

Comment: Nobody is "counting on" it being anything, and nobody is disputing this is undefined behavior. The point is that a segmentation fault is caused by attempting to access memory in a way that is not allowed, which just isn't what happens when you reference an uninitialized variable which obviously represents memory that you *are* allowed to access. Sure, anything can happen when you have undefined behavior, but a segfault still doesn't make much sense, here.

Comment: So your whole point is based on semantics?  Because OP tagged the post with the wrong error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received this error
[image]

`cout << "Enter your hourly rate: " << hourlyrate;`

You try to output the variable before you initialize it.
This is probably unintentional.

The next line is

`cin >> hourlyrate`

It is the same for every variable.  You should initialize them or not output them.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: I think it is.  It's why it failed for me.

Comment: The question was about a segfault though.  Did the code segfault when you tried it with an uninitialized value?

Comment: Possibly we are both using visual studio and you guys like g++ or something

Comment: That makes sense.  Also I think you can add images to your answer directly you don't need to include a link to an image hosting site.

Comment: The error you got was not a segfault. Who knows what's really going on in the OP's mind, but if he got the same error you did, I doubt he'd be asking the question, since it says right in it what the problem is.

Comment: I don't know.  If you look at the OP's code he's obviously a novice and perhaps having heard the term segfault he thinks that applies to any runtime error.

Comment: Yeah, depends on compiler is my point.  Maybe his threw some error and he didn't understand it.  I doubt you've never seen a case where one compiler had an ambiguous error while another did not.

Comment: Frankly, all the more reason why this isn't an answer, as much as a guess, but life goes on.

Comment: It's an answer if it fixes his problem then isn't it?  Maybe OP can add what compiler he's using and see if someone with it gets an ambiguous error or somehow a segfault.

Comment: I'm using Dev C++. I'm admittedly not familiar with my own compiler as of yet, and when I start debug it states that "an access violation (a segmentation fault) raised in my program"

I initially did receive an error in regards to uninitialized variables. So you are saying that before I cin >> variablename I'm trying to cout <<variablename when it has no definition stored correct? If so, would simply removing <<hourlyrate; for the example above correct the crash? Of course I would apply it to each line after that one.

Comment: Well, it's because you are trying to output a variable that you just declared.  It's contents could be anything at that point.  Left over data from an object destroyed.  Lots of compilers will automatically initialize variables to some default setting (like 0 or an empty string) but not all of them.  When you use `cout << variable;` you are making a call to an `operator<<()` overload in which your variable is passed to the function and used.  If it's not initialized yet, the results are unpredictable.

Comment: @user2793545 stop using Dev C++. Use GCC or Clang on Linux or Visual Studio on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about this:

```
cout << "Enter your hourly rate: " << hourlyrate; 
cin >> hourlyrate; 
cout << "Week 1: " << hweek1; 
cin >> hweek1; 
cout << "Week 2: " << hweek2; 
cin >> hweek2; 
cout << "Week 3: " << hweek3; 
cin >> hweek3; 
cout << "Week 4: " << hweek4; 
cin >> hweek4; 
cout << "Week 5: " << hweek5; 
cin >> hweek5;
```

I think that you wanted:

```
cout << "Enter your hourly rate: "; 
cin >> hourlyrate;
```

instead of:

```
cout << "Enter your hourly rate: "<< hourlyrate; 
cin >> hourlyrate;
```